# Form not rendering properly in Windows Forms Visual studio 2019

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, winforms

My form is not rendering properly after i used the status strip last night. Now, even if i recreate project, restart the application, restart the computer etc. It is the same. The designer view is normal.
This is an example of how button looks like: [image] The same goes for the strips, labels, etc. Also the status label is not updating like it should and the timer is not ticking. If i hover over the button, it fixes the looks but it doesnt work.
Also, i cannot open dialogs (filedialog, colordialog..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Invalidate() calling inside the Paint event in form1.cs, after deleting it everything works as it should do.

Comment: Hint: If you use a version control system (such as git) also on your smaller scale private projects, you can quickly identify changes if something unexpectedly breaks.

Comment: @Fetzy, I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.